# Pandas - max from DataFrame groupby return NAN

Tags: python, pandas, max

I have problem with my dataframe. I want get max values  from one column of groupedby DataFrame, but i get only NaNs...

My Dataframe

```
  kod_ow      kod_sw  ... pr_kierunkowa           infrast_h_bloku
0     06  061/200324  ...               None        0.000000
1     06  061/200324  ...               None        0.000000
2     06  061/200324  ...               None      209.365495
3     06  061/200324  ...               None        0.000000
4     06  061/200324  ...               None        0.000000
5     06  061/200324  ...               None      209.365495

[6 rows x 8 columns]
```

I've tried with:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(by=['kod_ow', 'kod_sw', 'nr_ks', 'nr_ks_pr', 'nazwa_zabiegu_icd_9', 'nazwa_zabiegu','pr_kierunkowa'])['infrast_h_bloku'].transform('max')
```

my result is:

```
  kod_ow      kod_sw  nr_ks  ... infrast_h_bloku osobodzien new
0     06  061/200324   3193  ...        0.000000        0.0 NaN
1     06  061/200324   3193  ...        0.000000        0.0 NaN
2     06  061/200324   3193  ...      209.365495        0.0 NaN
3     06  061/200324  54809  ...        0.000000        0.0 NaN
4     06  061/200324  54809  ...        0.000000        0.0 NaN
5     06  061/200324  54809  ...      209.365495        0.0 NaN
```

The question is, why max function put NAN in new column instead of real result???

Can someone help me, what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar example to get maximum col2 row for each id.

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
   
# dictionary of lists 
dict = {'id':[1, 1, 2, 2], 
        'col1':[21, 40, 81, 98], 
        'col2':[30, 20, 80, 91],
        'col3':[90, 10, 41, 99]
       } 
  
# creating a dataframe from a dictionary  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
  
df[df.groupby(by=['id'])['col2'].transform(max) == df['col2']]
```

So you can use this in your case like below:

```
 df.groupby(by=['kod_ow', 'kod_sw', 'nr_ks', 'nr_ks_pr', 'nazwa_zabiegu_icd_9', 'nazwa_zabiegu','pr_kierunkowa'])['infrast_h_bloku'].transform(max)==df['infrast_h_bloku']
```

Comment: Could you produce an example like mention below:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example